# l1magic error- How can I optimize a linear problem?

Tags: matlab, optimization

I am trying to use "l1eq_pd" from l1-magic package in MATLAB to solve a linear equation Ax=b. I got an error:

```
Starting point infeasible; using x0 = At*inv(AAt)*y.
Error using linsolve
Matrix must be positive definite.
```

When I delete the opts in the source code at line 77 it gives the error:

```
Starting point infeasible; using x0 = At*inv(AAt)*y.
A*At is ill-conditioned: cannot find starting point
```

I checked the A matrix in my code. It has size(A) = [388 425]. However, its rank(A) = 353 which means there are lots of linearly dependent columns. Is there any way to solve this problem? Or is the problem with my A matrix?

Thanks

Comment: *Or is the problem with my A matrix?*. That is what the error is telling you. Do you have any reason to doubt it?

Comment: Thanks Ander. I tried to solve the same problem with lsqminnorm and it gives an answer. That's why I thought maybe "l1eq_pd" method is not working for my problem.  As you might know, l1magic have 7 different solvers. I thought maybe I have to use another method.

Comment: Not all methods can solve all problems